# How to make an app available only to a certain states in a country

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to make an app available only to a certain states in India or any country? As per my research, I am only able to change the country but cannot narrow it down to states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible via the Google Play Store. However, one thing that you could do is to get the location of the user on first run and check if it is in the state or area where you don't want the app to work, then not to allow the user to do anything more. And if the user is in a area where you want app to be available, then and only then allow the user to move ahead.